# How can I search all hard coded text in an application React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I need to search and move in a file .json with  react i18n for internationalization. the hard coded text and make manually is so long and not sure. I want to use an automatic solution .

By example: 
before my check

```
function NotFoundPage(props) {
    const { t } = useTranslation("notFoundPage");
return (
    <Result
        status="404"
        title="404"
        subTitle="Sorry, the page you visited does not exist."
        extra={
            <Button
                type="primary"
                style={{ margin: "auto" }}
                onClick={() => props.history.push("/")}
            >
                Back to Projects
            </Button>
        }
    />
);
```

}

after my chech

```
function NotFoundPage(props) {
    const { t } = useTranslation("notFoundPage");
    return (
        <Result
            status="404"
            title="404"
            subTitle={t("Sorry, the page you visited does not exist.")}
            extra={
                <Button
                    type="primary"
                    style={{ margin: "auto" }}
                    onClick={() => props.history.push("/")}
                >
                    {t("Back to Projects")}
                </Button>
            }
        />
    );
}
```

the lines with "Sorry, ... " and "Back to ..." I change them for put it in the .json file but sometime in a long file isn't easy to find the hard coded text.

Comment: The keybinding 'ctrl/command + f'? Are you asking about searching in your text editor or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, ctrf+f is for finding a text in a file, I want to find in (sometimes long file +-700lines) the text hard coded for putting it in a file .json for internationalization..

Comment: @Mitch You may need to make it more specific, with some sample data from input to output perhaps

Comment: I need just find it  not move automatically

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression to find all html tags that starts with alphabetic characters. Those who are not hard coded would normally starts with a '{' (a JSX expression)

Below is an example in Visual Studio Code.
Crtl+SHIFT+F to search in all project.
Don't forget to choose to RegExp option in search bar.

[image: Find all hardcoded text in a React App]

Comment: Here is the Reg Ex to copy and paste: `>[A-Za-z]{1,}`. Cheers!